# React App : Process is not defined (dotenv) uncaught reference error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dotenv

I'm trying to use my api key as an env variable in my react application by defining it in the .env file. However when run "npm run dev" I get the console error process is not defined from lines

main.jsx

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

and

component.jsx

```
  const api_url =env.REACT_APP_API_URL
```

Ive setup my env var as follows:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload"
```

Answer (score 0):

use process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, also you don't need to import dotenv
create-react-app provides this functionality out of the box, assuming you're using react-scripts@0.5.0 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the word `process` in your `component.jsx` file.
You might check this line;

```
  const api_url =env.REACT_APP_API_URL
```

=>

```
  const api_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL ||  "http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload";
```